# Difference between TiProxy and TiViewProxy in titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-modules, titanium-proxy

I'm now developing a module for titanium application.
I have already created [**module**](https://github.com/Midhun-MP/MMP_SMS) using proxy. (TiProxy).
The new module I'm creating is based on view. So I'm trying to use TiViewProxy.

But I'm confused with some terms:

1. What is the major difference between `TiProxy` and `TiViewProxy` ?
2. Is there any naming convention for `TiViewProxy` files ? If we are using `TiProxy`, then we add proxy after the file name. Is there anything like for view proxy ?

I referred [**iOS Module Development Guide**](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide) but there is nothing about the naming convention.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`TiViewProxy` is special proxy that has "built in magic" for views. It participates, for example, in the UI layout cycle.

Assuming your module only has one view it wants to expose to Ti, you should call your view `<ModuleName>View` and your proxy `<ModuleName>ViewProxy`. This will have the benefit of participating in the built-in magic, and your ability to use `myModule.createView()` from within JS.

In the iOS module development it is mentioned that you should implement

`-(void)frameSizeChanged:(CGRect)frame bounds:(CGRect)bounds`

(probably by doing something like  `[TiUtils setView:myView positionRect:bounds];`) -- that's how Ti lets you know your view has been positioned/resized. If you changed your view's position/size you should let Ti know:

`[(TiViewProxy*)[self proxy] setHeight:NUMFLOAT(height)];`

(if, for example, your view changed its height)